# Is it true, that $e^{i \dot x^2 \dot n^2}$ is less or equal to 1?

Tags: real-analysis

We're trying to solve a math problem, and to do this we've come up with an answer that relies completely on the following inequality (with n being an arbitrarily high number)

$$ \dfrac{|e^{i \,x^2  n^2}| }{n^5  x^4} \leq \frac{1}{n^5}$$

As $x^4$ is a positive number, the denominator makes sense. The numerator, however, is what we're unsure of. Can someone explain why this inequality is correct or incorrect?

Edit: Elaborating on the problem:
Show that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{|e^{i\,  x^2  n^2}| }{n^5  x^4}   $$ is absolute and uniformly convergent (with x being a real number and n natural number).

We're using the weierstrass m-test, and have made the following conclusion:
$$ \dfrac{|e^{i\,  x^2  n^2}| }{n^5  x^4} \leq \frac{1}{n^5}$$

With $\frac{1}{n^5}$ being convergent, we've managed to find a sequence that lets us use the m-test to prove convergence in the series.

In this solution, however, we've used an inequality we can't explain.

Comment: What is $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{n}$?

Comment: For complete context, mention the problem you are working on.  Read up the "XY problem" to see why I ask you to do this.

Comment: n is a large natural number. x is a real number. It comes from a series, where we're trying to find use weierstrass m-test. The inequality expressed above, however, is the only thing we're unsure of.

Comment: @Robbert You said what $n$ and $x$ are but what is $\dot{n}$ and $\dot{x}?$

Comment: Great, thanks for that @Robbert

Comment: @sahibaArora That was a mistake. Removed the dots

Comment: Next time you want to use a multiplication dot, and you do **not** need it here, you can use \cdot .

Comment: @Sahiba, I think he did a mistake because he wrote “\dot” instead of “\cdot”, so it appears that dot above $n$ and $x$, but actually he just wanted to write the sign of multiplication.

Comment: $$ \dfrac{|e^{i\,  x^2  n^2}| }{n^5  x^4} \leq \frac{1}{n^5 a^4}$$ for all $x\in\left]-\infty,-a\right]\cup\left[a,+\infty\right[$ where $a>0$. So your series is uniformly convergent on $\left]-\infty,-a\right]\cup\left[a,+\infty\right[$ for any $a>0$, but it is absolutely convergent on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

For $t \in \mathbb R$ we have $|e^{it}|=1$, hence

$$\dfrac{|e^{i \dot x^2 \dot n^2}| }{n^5 * x^4}=\dfrac{1 }{n^5 * x^4},$$

Thus

$$\dfrac{|e^{i \dot x^2 \dot n^2}| }{n^5 * x^4} \leq \frac{1}{n^5} \iff x^4 \ge 1 \iff |x| \ge 1.$$

Comment: Can you explain why $|e^{it}|=1$? This is the part we're unsure of

Comment: @Robbert $$\lvert e^{it} \rvert = \lvert \cos(t) + i \sin(t) \rvert = \sqrt{\cos^{2}(t) + \sin^{2}(t)} = \sqrt{1}$$  For more information, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers).

Answer (score 0):

$$ \dfrac{|e^{i\,  x^2  n^2}| }{n^5  x^4} \leq \frac{1}{n^5 a^4}$$ for all $x\in\left]-\infty,-a\right]\cup\left[a,+\infty\right[$ where $a>0$.

So your series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{|e^{i\,  x^2  n^2}| }{n^5  x^4}$$ is uniformly convergent on $\left]-\infty,-a\right]\cup\left[a,+\infty\right[$ for any $a>0$, but it is absolutely convergent on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.